# angular JS exact filter in controller

Tags: angularjs, filter

$scope.gradeC = $filter('filter')($scope.results.subjects, {grade: 'C'})[0];

This will give matched results.

Any idea on how to filter only exact matches?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a strict comparator flag as an argument to the filter.

```
$scope.gradeC = $filter('filter')($scope.results.subjects, {grade: 'C'}, true)[0];
```

Ref: [Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) doc